# Group Administrator cannot change file right by chmod g+w

Tags: permissions, chmod

Already execute" **gpasswd -a**   " to assign a group administrator.
The one of group owner put a file as read only.

But group administrator can't change the file by" **chmod g+w files.txt**".

Error message shown
**chmod: changing permissions of `files.txt': Operation not permitted**

How to make the file has write permission in group?

Comment: Sorry, command is " gpasswd -A thomas_lin SW", SW is group name.

Comment: What do you mean by "group administrator"? `gpasswd -a` justs adds a user to a group.

Comment: If you meant `gpasswd -A` (upper case `A`) then I don't think it does what you think it does: a *group administrator* doesn't have any special rights over files owned by the group members - just over who belongs to the group.

Comment: The changes made in the `/etc/group` file take effect at `login` time. Did you logout and login?

Comment: Yes, I did logout and login. But fail. By the way, I ask for administrator's help(root). He has right to modify file.

Comment: Hi steeldriver, do you have any idea to get the right or fine a manage way?